# react-native-linear-gradient Only red border is visible on iOS

Tags: react-native-ios

On react-native iOS, "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.0.0".

After installing correctly this package with npm then using 'react-native link', i see a red border around my text but not any gradient with the example provided.

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

// Within your render function
<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Sign in with Facebook
  </Text>
</LinearGradient>

// Later on in your styles..
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out 
https://alligator.io/react/gradient-border-react-native/
I have solved this problem from this blog.
[image]

Code Example :

```
           <LinearGradient
              colors={["#FFA500", "#C5121B"]}
              start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
              end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
              style={{ borderRadius: 5 }}
            >
              <View style={styles.registerButtonStyle}>
                <Text>Register</Text>
              </View>
            </LinearGradient>


registerButtonStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
    paddingBottom: 7,
    paddingTop: 7,
    margin: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 5
```

},

Comment: First solution I see that works - Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Solved in my case with RN 0.41.2: run this command in the terminal 'react-native run-ios' for recompiling with xCode (necessary in general after a 'react-native link' command)